# My CIFAR10 model only get ~50% acc on validation set

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

Here's my code:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/sheeyxd/cifar10?kernelSessionId=95640783

there's 3 obvious questions I met in the training process:

1. the validation acc is higher than train acc at first epoch
2. the train acc keeps increasing at ~200 epoch but validation acc remains still.
3. the validation acc can't get higher than ~50%(current model) or ~65%(the commented code).

I have tried various ways to optimize it:

1. train 1000 epoches
2. normlize the image with mean (.5, .5, .5) and std (.3, .3, .3)
3. adjust the learning rate(1e-3 to 1e-7)
   these may increase the acc by 1% or 2%, but none of these really helps

I tried exame the dataset, it has been regularized(by deviding 255), and well performed in someone else' code.

So which part am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cifar10 is a hard dataset to generalize, you need to consider Transfer Learning if you want better results.

Comment: Thank you @Frightera, is it means that ~65% is the max acc I will reach if I am not using transfer learning? I see there's many articles say that they get ~90% acc on validation set using neither transfer learning nor normalization.

Comment: I did not say that, you may obtain ~90% accuracy, that depends on the model. Your current model seems so shallow.

Comment: thanks, I try more deeper model right away!